# Bind strings with quotation

Tags: c#, r.net

I am sending some code to R.net wrapper as strings. If there are no any quation marks inside , it's simple with @

```
 engine.Evaluate(@"remove_outliersabove <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) { 
                        qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...);
                        H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm);
                        y <- x;
                        y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA;
                        y;
                        }");
```

but if I have "" inside then things get complicated and I need to cut and join strings like this

```
    engine.Evaluate("for (k in 1:length(dates))" +
                    "{ " +
                        "tmp <- grep(dates[[k]],as.Date(data$timestamp, format=\"%d/%m/%Y\"))" +
                        "if (length(tmp)!=96)" +
                            "{ " +
                            "to_remove[[it]]=k it=it+1" +
                            "}" +
                    "}");
```

is there better option ? for example to use @ and then mark quation mark somehow ?

Comment: If you use `@` then to add a `"` you'll simply need to double it `""`. In the end there is little difference to not using `@` and escaping the `"` with `\"`

Comment: @xanatos great that works, Didn't know about double "" when using @, please change your comment into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@"..."`, you can escape the `"` character by doubling it to `""`. So

```
string str = "hello ""world""!";
```

is

```
hello "world"!
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `string.Format("{0} bla bla {1}",string1,string2)`? does it make it look neater?

Comment: no I dont' wanna breake original code formating, looks better to read.